# Reactive Form Array Object updated but Virtual Scroll list not updating on Front End

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

**Reproduction:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rf-virtual-scroll

**Expected Behavior:** 
Data should append in Virtual Scroll list in UI

**Actual Behavior**

=> Virtual Scroll list not updating (front end)
=> Reactive Form Array Object updated perfectly (in ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because angular change detection will only trigger if the reference of an object changed. But by adding new elements the reference of your `items.controls` array stays the same.

You could create a copy of the `controls array` after adding a new one like:

```
addOneNew(item = [true, 9999999]){
  const obj = this.createItem(item)
  this.items.push(obj);
  this.items.controls = [...this.items.controls]
  console.log(this.items.value)
}
```

By assigning a new array, change detection will see your changes and update your view.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps...

**app.component.html**

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="content" [formGroup]="testForm">
        <ng-container formArrayName="data" *ngFor="let item of testForm.get('data')['controls']; let i = index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                Name: <input class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" type="text" formControlName="name">
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addItem()">Add Name</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 testForm: FormGroup;
 currentIndex = 0;
 constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder
 ) {}

 ngOnInit() {    
  this.testForm = this.createTestForm();
  this.initializeArray();
 console.log(this.testForm);

}

createTestForm(): FormGroup {
 return this.formBuilder.group({
   data: this.formBuilder.array([])
 });
}

get data(): FormArray {
 return this.testForm.get('data') as FormArray;
}

initializeArray() {
 for (let index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
   this.addItem();
 }
}

 addItem() {
   this.data.push(this.formBuilder.group({name: [`Name${this.data.length}`]}));
   this.currentIndex = this.data.length;
 }

 }
```